# How to Marry Local apache web domain?

Tags: javascript, apache, apache2, sails.js

I bought a domain on internet, i want on that domain put my application. My application was developed on Sails.js, and i made a virtual host with apache2 using the module mod_proxy.
How do I do to on the domain i bought on internet, put my application?

My virtual host is:

```
NameVirtualHost 111.11.11.111
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  app.domain.com.ve
    ServerAlias www.app.domain.com.ve
    ServerAdmin 111.11.11.111:1337
    RewriteEngine   on

    ProxyPass / http://111.11.11.111:1337/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://111.11.11.111:1337/

    CustomLog /home/user/app/apache2log/accessApp.log combined
    ErrorLog /home/user/app/apache2log/errorApp.log
</VirtualHost>
```

And my /etc/hosts:

```
111.11.11.111       www.app.domain.com.ve
```

Answer (score 0):

You isp will provide a administration panel to update the [A Record](https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/setting-custom-a-records/). You need to update your DNS records to point to your server where your application is hosted.

You need to host in a datacenter. Try AWS/Azure/Google Cloud/linode that provides a small server and provides an external network interface on the internet. Publish your application on that host. You should be able to access your application by your public IP. You can then go your domain control panel and modify your A Record.

Comment: My application is in my PC. What should I do?